# AWS create-policy MalformedPolicyDocument

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, syntax, command-line-interface

I did not find the solution here so I need to ask you for some help.
I am trying to create a new simple aws policy (cli) with powershell and I have the error:

> An error occurred (MalformedPolicyDocument) when calling the
> CreatePolicy operation: Syntax errors in policy.

This is the command I use:

```
aws iam create-policy --policy-name TEST-POLICY --policy-document file://policy.json
```

And this is the policy.json file:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:GetUser",
                "iam:GetGroup"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::(arn id):user/(arn id)",
                "arn:aws:iam::(arn id):group/(arn id)"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

It is strange because when I use the AWS website JSON editor it works fine. But when I try it on my windows pc does not.

Someone can see the wrong syntax?

Comment: I wrote (arn id) but there is an ID in the real file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. It was because the encoding UTF-8-BOM. It must be UTF-8